# Сравнить почту с логином js

Tags: javascript

Помогите дописать код
Мне нужно проверить что бы поле почты до @ равнялось логину.
К примеру логин gt-232425 а почта gt-232425@mail.ru
Как написать если содержимое поля логин  до собаки не равняется полю почты.

Comment: В чём трудность? Что вы уже пытались сделать?

Answer (score 3):

в данном случае удобно будет использовать метод split, который разбивает по указанному разделителю строку на массив элементов подстрок.

```
const email = 'example@mail.ru';
const login = 'notEqual';

const emailParts = email.split('@'); // emailParts[0] === 'example'

if (emailParts[0] !== login) {
    console.log('OMFG!');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Еще можно использовать метод String.prototype.startsWith().

```
const email = 'my_login@gmail.com'
const login = 'my_login'

if (!email.startsWith(login)) {
    console.log('Fail')
}
```

Comment: `if (!email.startsWith(login + "@"))`

Comment: `'my_login'` и `'my_login123@gmail.com'` - равняется?